# How to say during job interview that I would like to wait for other offers?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I graduated recently in Europe and am now looking for jobs in industry. I have sent 4 applications in the past week for position that I all find interesting - some more than others.

I have been invited for an introductory interview in the coming week, which is great. However, this position is not the one I find the most interesting out of the 4.

Depending on how the interview progresses, is there a way to politely say that I am also looking into other options at the moment and ask to what extent this potential offer is open? And is it even OK to say that?

Comment: *ask to what extent this potential offer is open* - what do you mean by this? Are you trying to ask "by when are you aiming to fill this position?"

Comment: @Brandin Yes, basically. It would be nice for me to see what other options i have before saying yes to the first one I am (maybe) offered

Comment: Ask them about their timeline (e.g. "when are you looking for someone to start?") but wait for the actual offer before you say "I would like to wait for other offers."

Comment: You're getting ahead of yourself here.  It's just the first interview.  There will probably be multiple interviews - you don't need to even bring up the subject until they're actually giving you an offer & you're considering the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "I have some more applications where I expect offers very soon, and I would like to wait for these offers". And then you see how it goes and play it accordingly.

And you're overthinking things. "Will this not give a wrong impression in the sense that they think I am not motivated enough for work there?" Any company knows that they are not the only company in the universe. Any company *expects* you to look for jobs elsewhere - unless the company is run by some maniac who can't stand the idea, and then I can promise you that working for that company would be hell.

Now if they want to hire someone within the next week, and you want to wait four weeks for offers, that's a problem (that's why I said you see how it goes and play accordingly). But if the fact that you are looking for other offers is something they don't like, look elsewhere. And some companies are afraid that you might get offers elsewhere because you would then realise that the company isn't offering what you are worth.

Comment: Will this not give a wrong impression in the sense that they think I am not motivated enough for work there?

Comment: @BillyJean If they make an offer, you can ask "how soon do you need an answer?" It shows you are considering their time requirements, not a lack of motivation. If you just say "Let me get back to you" and are vague or take too long, however, they might assume you are not motivated.

Answer (score 1):

When someone is looking for a job is certain that he applied for more that one position, recruiters know this.

I usually say that would find the perfect position for me, and would wait some days/week to make the right decison.

this kind of answer i perfectly polite, and remember that also recriter interview more that one person and wait before giving final feedback.